# Adding pause on hover support to multi-ticker concept

Tags: jquery

```
function tick(){
    $('.ticker').each(function(){
        $(this).find('li:first').slideUp(function () {
            $ticker = $(this).closest('.ticker');
            $(this).appendTo($ticker).slideDown();
        });
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 5000);
```

I indent to use this multi-ticker concept on my page [shown on JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpr9t/4/). Like it a lot but its missing something. A pause on hover.

So, I wish to put a "pause on hover" feature `for each` ticker here in following manner:

- hovered ticker will stop sliding up, while others will continue sliding up (and so on/vice verssa).

Possible? I'm really bad with jquery, so I need help here.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fQ9XG/)***

You can do this by setting a class name on `.ticker` to indicate pause when one of the `.ticker` elements is hovered over

```
$('.ticker').hover(function(){
 $(this).addClass('pause');//mouse enter
},function(){
 $(this).removeClass('pause');//mouse leave
});
```

And then screen for that in your tick function's `.each` iteration (return true is used by jQuery as a psuedo `continue`)

```
if($(this).hasClass('pause'))return true;//continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpr9t/8/

```
var hoveredElement=null;

function tick(){
    $('.ticker').filter(function(item){   
                return !$(this).is(hoveredElement)
            }).each(function(){
        $(this).find('li:first').slideUp(function () {                       
            $ticker = $(this).closest('.ticker');

            $(this).appendTo($ticker).slideDown();
        });
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);


$(function(){
    $('.ticker').hover(function(){
hoveredElement=$(this);        
    },function(){
        hoveredElement=null;
    });
});
```